# Explain what those escaped numbers mean in unicode encoding in ruby 1.8.7

Tags: ruby, unicode

0186 is the unicode "code". Where do 198 and 134 come from? How can go the other way around, from these byte codes to unicode strings?

```rb
>> c = JSON '["\\u0186"]'
[
    [0] "Ɔ"
]
>> c[0][0]
198
>> c[0][1]
134
>> c[0][2]
nil
```

Another confusing thing is unpack. Another seemingly arbitrary number. Where does that come from? Is it even correct? From the [1.8.7 String#unpack documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/String.html#method-i-unpack):

U    | Integer | UTF-8 characters as unsigned integers

```
>> c[0].unpack('U')
[
    [0] 390
]
>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find your answers here [Unicode Character 'LATIN CAPITAL LETTER OPEN O' (U+0186)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/186/index.htm):

- Note that 186 (hexadecimal) === 390 (decimal)
- C/C++/Java source code : "\u0186"
- UTF-32 (decimal) : 390
- UTF-8 (hex) : 0xC6 0x86 (i.e. 198 134)

You can read more about UTF-8 encoding on Wikipedia's article on [UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8).

- UTF-8 (UCS Transformation Format — 8-bit[1]) is a variable-width encoding that can represent every character in the Unicode character set. It was designed for backward compatibility with ASCII and to avoid the complications of endianness and byte order marks in UTF-16 and UTF-32.